# Best way to request and display "you have x new messages"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optimization

I have a messaging system for members on my ASP.NET MVC website.
Messages are flagged as read or unread.

Now I'd like to display in the navigation bar a label wich says "you have x new messages" if there is any. This, wherever I am on the website (not only on the discussion page).

I could do a request for retrieving the number of unread messages on every page of the website but it seems bad to me.

What other ways do you recommand ? (caching, cookie, etc.)
I assume it is a well know scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could try another approach: Store the number of unread message for the first time. Use somethings like [`SignalR`](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to notification and change the number when user receive new message

Comment: Real-time notifications are not really necessary for now, refreshing on each http request should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in handling this in real time think about SignalR technology: http://signalr.net/.

If not you can think about BaseController and BaseViewModel with MessagesCount property.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a table with `Messages`:

```
Id             INT
Created        DATETIME
ReceiverUserId INT
Message        NVARCHAR(MAX)
...
```

If you want to get a count of new messages since some date/time (call it `LastVisited`), you could use SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Messages
 WHERE ReceiverUserId = @CurrentUserId
   AND Created > @LastVisited
```

Would this query a fast? Yes, if you created an index `(ReceiverUserId, Created)`.
But this value is changed infrequently, so you can use a cache.

If you use IoC container, such as Autofac, Castle Windsor, and so on, you can create a different container for each logged-in user, and store user-specific objects (values) in this container.

You also could store this primitive value (the count of new messages) just in `Session`.

Comment: How to unvalidate cache for reciever user when a message is sent to him ?

Comment: You can use two basic methods: re-read value from DB after a time interval, or do some actions at message's sending (you can call this *notification*, but it's not the only one). In a case of IoC you could update or reset a count of messages in the recipient's container directly.